# Как предоставить реализацию для чисто виртуальной функции, оставляя ее таковой в C++?

Tags: c++

Как предоставить реализацию для чисто виртуальной функции, оставляя ее таковой в C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С++ позволяет задавать определение чисто виртуальной функции.

```
    abstract class Base
    {
        public:
            virtual void SomeVirtualFunc() = 0;
    }

    void Base::SomeVirtualFunc()
    {
        // Код по умолчанию
    }
```

Класс остается абстрактным и требует переопределения виртуальной функции, но некоторым потомкам будет пригодна реализация по умолчанию. Это будет выглядеть так.

```
    class Derived : public Base
    {
        public:
            virtual void SomeVirtualFunc();
    }

    void Derived::SomeVirtualFunc()
    {
            // Данный вызов легален. Будет выполнен вызов функции базового класса.
            Base::SomeVirtualFunc();
    }
```